# Array_map versus array walk because of warning issues

Tags: php

Hi i have a simple question 
I am using array_walk to encode an array to utf8 like this :

```
  array_walk($row, 'utf8_encode');
```

but i keep on getting a php warning this one

```
   (PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for utf8_encode() ).
```

So i was wondering does using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead to encode to utf8 (`array_walk('utf8_encode',$row);`) have the same effect, because with array map i don't have the warning issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your `$row` look like?

Comment: $row is the resulting array of mysql_fetch_row($res)

Comment: You should be setting the connection parameter of MySQL to `utf8`, not encode the data after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, array_map is better for you. Because you want to encode only the values of your row. `array_walk` requires the callback function to accept 2 parameters: value and key.

As you are not going to encode the key, it will be more efficient to use array_map.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 1):

That's because, utf8_encode expects only 1 param, but [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) gives 2. You can do it like:

```
function encode_items(&$item, $key) {
    $item = utf8_encode($item);
}
array_walk($row, 'encode_items');
```

or supress warning (not good)

```
@array_walk($row, 'utf8_encode');
```

or better use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function utf8_encode_array($array) {
    return array_map('utf8_encode', $array);
}
$encoded = array_map('utf8_encode_array', $row);
```

Answer (score 0):

[utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) has a single parameter, fix:

```
array_walk($row, function (&$value,$key) {
    return utf8_encode($value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_walk` passes two parameters to the callback: the value and the key. `utf8_encode` expects *one* parameter and hence complains. `array_map` will work better here since it doesn't pass additional parameters to the callback:

```
$row = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
```

Having said that, in 99% of all cases `utf8_encode` is the wrong thing to use. Read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).